# How to access Nested Objects

Tags: javascript, graphql

#### GraphQL Nested Mutations

How do I access created ingredients  key/value?

This's the `ingredients` query:

```
ingredients{
    amount 
    unit 
    food{
      bls 
     name 
    kcal
   }
}
```

```
mutation {
  createRecipe(
    data: {
      title: "ABC"
      author: "XYZ"
      level:  EASY
      ingredients: {amount: 250, unit: GRAMM,  food:  {name: "Flour", bls: "xxx", kcal: 203}
       }
    }
```

#### Resolver

```
Mutation: {
  createRecipe: (_, args) => {
    const newRecipe = {
      title: args.data.title,
      author: args.data.author,
      level: args.data.level,
      ingredients: args.........??????
    };
}
}
```

#### Results

```
"data": {
    "createRecipe": {
      "title": "ABC",
      "author": "XYZ",
      "level": "EASY",
      "ingredients": null,
    }
  }
```

How do I access `ingredients' amount, unit` then `ingredients food name,bls,kcal` and populate the ingredients array that is on gql playground?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by keys&values - do you want to create a relation to an existing row/entry in the `ingredients` collection? You can just input an array of ingredient IDs, get the ingredients from IDs using your database driver in the resolver and then assign the `ingredients` property in your input

Comment: Could you please demonstrate the wanted structure?

Comment: Have tried to make it a little bit clear. See edits.

Comment: I assume you want to move all properties of `food` to `ingredients`? You can just write `ingredients: {amount: args.data.ingredients.amount, unit: args.data.ingredients.unit, ...args.data.ingredients.food}`